# Relatively simple Linear Algebra inquiry

Tags: linear-algebra

Thank you for reading. I'm looking at the following... I am looking to prove that the following either is or is not a vector space by checking all eight properties...

Let $$V := \{(a_1,a_2) : a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb R\}$$. Define addition of elements of $V$ coordinate-wise, and for $(a_1, a_2) \in V$ and $c\in \mathbb R$, define..
$$c(a_1,a_2)= \begin{cases} (0,0) & \text{if } c=0 \\ \left(ca_1, \frac{a_2}{c}\right) & \text{else}\end{cases}$$

Now, I have the solution which says that it is not a VS because of the following...
$$(c+d)(a_1,a_2) = \left((c+d)a_1,\frac{a_2}{c+d}\right) \neq c(a_1,a_2) + d(a_1,a_2) = \left(ca_1 + da_1, \frac{a_2}{c} + \frac{a_2}{d}\right)$$

Would someone please explain to me how they reached this conclusion. Please keep in mind that have not had Abstract Algebra yet so... And if a mod could clean it up a little that would be awesome as well. Thanks everyone. -court

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof concludes by
$$\frac{x}{c+d} \neq \frac{x}{c} + \frac{x}{d}$$
This can be see for example by chosing $c = d = 1$ and $x\neq 0$, so
$$\frac{x}{2} \neq 2x$$
Using this, the factorisation law
$$\lambda v + \mu v = (\lambda + \mu) v \qquad \forall\ \lambda, \mu \in \mathbb R, v\in V$$
Fails for the second component

Comment: No problem. If this solved it for you, please mark the question as solved. Else ask anything which remained unclear.

Comment: Which property would you be checking that would place d in the denominator? The additive identity?

Comment: It's what I call the factorisation law above, check your notes if you find a similar one under another name. I have added the equation which fails to the answer.

Comment: I see it now. Thank you a lot. How do I mark it solved?

Comment: Click the grey checkmark below the Up/Downvote buttons to the left of the answer. It will become green.